# The equivariant BSD conjecture (and the $\rho$-isotypical component)

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, l-functions

I am trying to understand the statement of the equivariant BSD conjecture.

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. Let $\rho$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible Artin representation, and let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be any finite Galois extension such that $\rho$ factors through $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$.

I have seen the equivariant BSD conjecture stated as:

\begin{equation}\tag{1} \mathrm{ord}_{s=1}L(E,\rho,s)=\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{C}\,E^{(\rho)}, \end{equation}

where $E^{(\rho)}$ is the $\rho$-isotypical component of $E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C}$. However, I have also seen the conjecture stated as:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\mathrm{ord}_{s=1}L(E,\rho,s)= \text{multiplicity of $\rho$ in $E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C}.$}
\end{equation}

**Here is my confusion:** If the dimension of $\rho$ is not 1, aren't these different statements?

---

For some context, in the representation theory textbooks I have read, the multiplicity and isotypical components are defined as follows:

Given a finite-dimensional complex representation V (of a finite group G), we can canonically decompose V into a direct sum of its irreducible components
$$V=\bigoplus_{I\in\mathrm{\,IrrReps}(G)}I^{\oplus\, m(I,V)}\quad\quad\text{(with $m(I,V)=0$ for almost all $I$)}.$$
Then, for each $I$, they define:

> The $I$-isotypical component of $V$ is the summand $V^{(I)}:=I^{\oplus\, m(I,V)}$.

> The multiplicity of $I$ in $V$ is the exponent $m(I,V)$.

In particular, we have
$$\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{C} V^{(I)} = m(I,V) \,\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{C} I.$$

---

So, going back to conjectures (1) and (2), if $\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{C} \rho\neq 1$, the statements are not the same. Which one is correct? Have I misunderstood something?

I suspect some authors mean a different thing when they say "$\rho$-isotypical component", which may be the source of my confusion.

Comment: Those are different statements as far as I know. Do you know any sources where an explicit example is worked out that could disambiguate them?

Comment: I'm inclined to believe it should be 2, as stated in [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle-2020-0036/html). For example, let $\rho = \mathrm{Ind}_L^K(\chi)$ for some character $\chi$. The usual Artin formulism should give $L(E, \rho, s) = L(E/L, \chi, s)$. The latter is $\dim \mathrm{Hom}_{G_L}(\chi, E(L)\otimes\mathbb C)$ by either definition. But by Frobenius reciprocity, this is the same as $\dim \mathrm{Hom}_{G_K}(\rho, E(L)\otimes \mathbb C)$. Is this the same as the multiplicity of $\rho$ in $E(K)\otimes \mathbb C$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan All examples I know concern the classical BSD or its twists by a simple Dirichlet character (but in these cases $\mathrm{dim}_\mathbb{C}\,\rho=1$). In fact, I don't even know how to effectively compute these things in general. As far as I know, computing the rank of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ already is quite complicated, so finding the multiplicity of a given $\rho$ in $E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C}$ might be even harder.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes, your reasoning makes sense. Thanks! I'm also inclined to believe the correct conjecture is (2). The dimension of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})}(\rho,E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C})$ is exactly the multiplicity of $\rho$ in $E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C}$ (because $\rho$ is irreducible). In fact, as mentioned, I suspect that some authors mean a different thing when they say ``$\rho$-isotypical component" (it seems that they mean this space you mentioned).

Comment: @Mathmo123 For example, in the first page of [this paper](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/63.DR2/DR2.pdf) they state the conjecture as (1), however, they define the ``$\rho$-isotypical component" as being the space $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})}(\rho,E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C})$ so, by the above comment, their conjecture is actually (2). This different usage of terminology might be the source of my confusion.

Comment: I have been trying to make sense of this different usage of terminology, but I still can't understand why they refer to $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})}(\rho,E(K)\otimes\mathbb{C})$ as the "$\rho$-isotypical component". As far as I can tell, this space is not "$\rho$-isotypic" in any sense (since $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ acts trivially on it) and it is also not a "component" (it is not even a subspace). I wish someone could shed light on this, just to confirm if this is indeed just a matter of different terminology, or if I am missing something from the picture.

Comment: I would call that hom the multiplicity space of $\rho$ rather than the $\rho$-isotypic component. It sounds like there is different usage of terminology here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked in this area a fair bit myself, I can confirm that the correct statement of equivariant BSD is statement (2), namely

$\operatorname{ord}_{s = 1} L(E, \rho, s) = \operatorname{dim} \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Gal}(K / \mathbf{Q})}(\rho, E(K) \otimes \mathbf{C})$

for any $K$ such that $\rho$ factors through $\operatorname{Gal}(K / \mathbf{Q})$.

As for the terminology: "multiplicity space" is probably the more correct term for this Hom-space, while "$\rho$-isotypic component" should be the sum of the *images* of all the Homs in this space. But some authors do indeed use "isotypic component" to mean the Hom-space itself (even though it is not a subspace of $E(K) \otimes \mathbf{C}$); it's just a quirk of the literature one needs to get used to.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this! The different usage of the term "$\rho$-isotypic component" had me very confused.